# The size of image was changed after using wavelet transformation

Tags: python, opencv

My code is:

```
def Wavelet(img):
"""Using Wavelet transform to denoise"""
img=img/255
results=[]
R, G, B=cv2.split(img)
channels=[R,G,B]
for channel in channels:
    coeffs = pywt.dwt2(channel, 'haar')
    cA, (cH, cV, cD) = coeffs
    cA1=cv2.blur(cA,(5,5),cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    cH1 = cv2.blur(cH, (5, 5), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    cV1 = cv2.blur(cV, (5, 5), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    cD1 = cv2.blur(cD, (5, 5), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    coeffs1=cA1,(cH1,cV1,cD1)
    result=pywt.idwt2(coeffs1,'haar')
    results.append(result)

result_img = cv2.merge([results[0], results[1], results[2]])
```

After using the wavelet transformation, I found that the size of the image changed. The original size is 740*389, but the processed size is 740*390. I don’t want to deal with the border of the image, what should I do？

Comment: Which version of opencv are you using? You can try to specify what happens with the borders by passing in another argument e.g. cv2.blur(img,(5,5),cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT). Possible values can be found in this table: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/opencv-python-program-to-blur-an-image

Comment: My version of opencv is 3.4.2. I use cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT but it still change the size of image.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using a window size of (5x5) , so the image size is rounded off to nearby multiple of 5, I dont think you can change it , other than resizing it.
refer to the example of [cv2.blur()](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html) here.

Answer (score 0):

Blur function doesn't change your size of image. If you read the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga8c45db9afe636703801b0b2e440fce37), it says:

> Output image: image of the same size and type as source image.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I find my error. It is not Blur function' s fault.